# React Native Elements cannot be used as a JSX component - Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

`'Text' cannot be used as a JSX component.`

Im using the `Text` elements as example but it happens for all react native elements.

Code example:

```
  return (
    <>
      <TechnicianDetailCard technicianData={technicianData} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          saveContact();
        }}
      >
        <Text>Add To contacts</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          copyPhoneNumber();
        }}
      >
        <Text>Copy Phone Number</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </>
  );
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the project was taking the
`@react-native-types` from the another `node_modules` project

Answer (score 0):

First, check if all the files that contain some JSX are named with a `.tsx` extension. Second, check the `compilerOptions` of your `tsconfig.json` in the root of your project.
It should contain something similar to the following according to the react-native documentation.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Both steps are documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) and [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript).

If the above does not apply to you, then try to update your `@types/react-native`. If you are using `npm`, then this works as follows.

```js
npm install --save @types/react-native
```

If you are using `yarn`, then this works as follows.

```js
yarn add @types/react-native
```

Comment: None of them works :(